# count no. of dates per ID after a match

Tags: r, sorting, date, count, match

I want to create a column (res) in df1 that lists a count (which will be descending) for each ID. This column will match date B and date C count how many dates C (from df2) are greater than dateA. There will be more dates in Date C per ID than Date B.

df1

```
ID  date A      date B
17  27/06/12    26/07/12
17  21/02/13    21/02/13
17  23/01/14    23/01/14
17  5/02/15     5/02/15
17  28/11/16    16/06/16 
18  25/07/13    22/05/13
18  29/10/14    1/12/14
18  11/05/15    1/12/14
21  27/09/12    16/07/12
21  25/07/14    11/08/14
21  15/07/15    24/02/15
```

df2

```
ID  date C
17  09/02/12
17  26/07/12
17  21/02/13
17  23/01/14
17  19/06/14
17  24/07/14
17  5/02/15
17  26/02/15
17  28/05/15
17  20/08/15
17  24/03/16
17  16/06/16
18  22/05/13
18  16/10/13
18  5/05/14
18  1/12/14
21  16/07/12
21  27/05/13
21  10/02/14
21  11/08/14
21  24/02/15
```

df1 with new column added:

```
df1
ID  date A      date B     res
17  27/06/12    26/07/12    11
17  21/02/13    21/02/13    9
17  23/01/14    23/01/14    8
17  5/02/15     5/02/15     5
17  28/11/16    16/06/16    0 
18  25/07/13    22/05/13    3
18  29/10/14    1/12/14     1
18  11/05/15    1/12/14     0
21  27/09/12    16/07/12    4
21  25/07/14    11/08/14    2
21  15/07/15    24/02/15    0
```

Comment: Please refrain from giving col names with spaces in them

Answer (score 2):

The `data.table` package is very well suited for this kind of non-equi joins.

```
df1[, res:=0L][match(df2$dateC, dateB), 
    res := df2[.SD, on=.(ID, dateC > dateA), .N, by=.EACHI]$N]
df1
```

In the above code, initialize the result to 0.

Then, you subset `df1` by matching values between `dateB` and `dateC`.

Then you join the subseted `df1` with `df2` using `ID` and `dateC > dateA`.

For each row of `df1` (i.e. `.EACHI`), return the number of rows.

Since the results is a data.table, `$N` will return the column named N after calculating.

Or alternatively, using equi-join

```
df1[, res:=0L][df2, on=.(ID, dateB=dateC), 
    res := df2[.SD, on=.(ID, dateC > dateA), .N, by=.EACHI]$N][]
```

data:

```
library(data.table)

df1 <- fread("ID  dateA      dateB
17  27/06/12    26/07/12
17  21/02/13    21/02/13
17  23/01/14    23/01/14
17  5/02/15     5/02/15
17  28/11/16    16/06/16 
18  25/07/13    22/05/13
18  29/10/14    1/12/14
18  11/05/15    1/12/14
21  27/09/12    16/07/12
21  25/07/14    11/08/14
21  15/07/15    24/02/15")
cols <- c("dateA", "dateB")
df1[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.Date, format="%d/%m/%y"), .SDcols=cols]

df2 <- fread("ID  dateC
17  09/02/12
17  26/07/12
17  21/02/13
17  23/01/14
17  19/06/14
17  24/07/14
17  5/02/15
17  26/02/15
17  28/05/15
17  20/08/15
17  24/03/16
17  16/06/16
18  22/05/13
18  16/10/13
18  5/05/14
18  1/12/14
21  16/07/12
21  27/05/13
21  10/02/14
21  11/08/14
21  24/02/15")
df2[, dateC := as.Date(dateC, "%d/%m/%y")]
```

Comment: thank you chinsoon and @David Arenburg, this works partially. But I also get "NA"s in the res column.  I will load more data as an example to see if that helps

Comment: @sar you will get `NA` in case there is no match between `dateC` and `dateB` columns. For instance,  in your new data, in row #8 `df1` there is no matching date in `df2$dateC` to `df1$dateB`

Comment: @sar In either way, you can easily replace NAs with zeroes by doing `df1[is.na(res), res := 0]`